# How to make files with a loop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I have a fasta file for which I want to make separated files for each sequence. The name of the file for each sequence should be unique so I used the description of the sequence. It gives an error for: `output=open(header,"w")` The error says: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '>g1.fasta'
The code:

```
    in_file = open("test.fasta","r")
lines=in_file.read().strip()

lines=lines.replace("\r\n","\n")
in_file.close()

sequences=lines.split("\n>")

in_file.close()
print(sequences)

for sequence in sequences:
    elements=sequence.split("\n")
    header = elements[0]
    seq = "".join(elements[1:])
    name=header+".fasta"
    output=open(name,"w")
    output.write(seq)
    output.close()
```

Comment: please provide an example of test.fasta file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming test.fasta content is:

```
>SEQUENCE_1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL
>SEQUENCE_2
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
```

I'd suggest this:

```
with open('test.fasta', 'r') as file:
    raw = file.read()

clean = raw.strip().replace('\r\n', '\n').split('>')
sequences = [sequence for sequence in clean if sequence]

print(sequences)

for sequence in sequences:
    elements = sequence.split("\n")
    header = elements[0]
    seq = ''.join(elements[1:])
    name = header + '.fasta'
    with open(name, 'w') as output:
        output.write(seq)
```